# MySQL: What does % stand for in host column and how to change user's password

Tags: mysql

Well, this is what I can see:

```
select host, user from mysql.user;

+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | me               |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| ::1       | root             |
| localhost |                  |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | root             |
| ubuntu    |                  |
| ubuntu    | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

I entered as root and would like to change password for user 'me'.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'%' = PASSWORD('letmein');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Well, no rows affected as we can see.

As for trying to access, the result is as follows:

```
Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
michael@ubuntu:/var/www/cgi-bin$
```

So, it mentions localhost, not %.

Could you suggest me how to change the password for 'me' and explain what % is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set password for `localhost`:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('letmein');

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

`%` means remote hosts can login to MySQL server from any other server whereas localhost means you can login to MySQL server only from same machine.

Comment: mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('letmein');
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

Comment: if you want to access from local machine then you need to create user `'me'@'localhost'` or use `-h 'server_ip'` in login command

Comment: Me already exists. CREATE USER 'me'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'letmein';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'me'@'localhost'
As for logging in, I forgot my password.

Comment: Maybe I should just kill 'me'?

Comment: Tried another user: CREATE USER 'myself'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'letmein';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: Well, strange. It wrote that 0 rows affected. But when I showed all users, I didn't see 'me', but saw 'myself'. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

'%' mean you can login into database from any host connected to those database. You also define your localhost as host if you want to access database from localhost.

to change your password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'%' = PASSWORD('letmein');
```

and don't forget execute:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

to commit your change. Please look at [MySql Account Management.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/adding-users.html)

**UPDATE:**

As on your user table I not found username with host = localhost you must create this user first by (here to [add user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/adding-users.html)):

```
Grant all privileges on *.* to me@'localhost' identified by 'letmein';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'%' = PASSWORD('letmein');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
michael@ubuntu:/var/www/cgi-bin$ mysql -u me -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Well, not working. 0 rows affected both times. And of course access denied.

Comment: No, not working. SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('letmein'); Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Maybe this is because I happen to forgot the password for me. So it is a loop: you can't change your host because you don't remember your password and you can't change your password because you can't access your host.

Comment: check your password format, Maybe your database use MD5 for hash a password. If database use MD5 for hash password, you must change to:
SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'localhost' = MD5('letmein');

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR 'me'@'localhost' = MD5('letmein');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MD5('letmein')' at line 1
How to check wheter it is MD5 or not?

Comment: Thank you. But I just killed 'me' and created another user at localhost.

Comment: What  does both of them mean % and localhost, does it mean he can access from both or one will clear other role.