# MYSQL: diference into CREATE USER 'user'@'%' vs CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost'?

Tags: mysql

Into MySQL as user ROOT I run `CREATE USER 'deletethisuser01'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'jump!';`
result = OK

Also I run `CREATE USER 'deletethisuser02'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'jump!';`
result = OK

please what is the difference into `'@'` vs `'localhost'` ?

but now I run:

`DROP USER 'deletethisuser01';` = `OK`

`DROP USER 'deletethisuser02';` =  `#1396 - Operation DROP USER failed for 'deletethisuser02'@'%'`

why this error?, how I can delete the user 'deletethisuser02' ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: What does % stand for in host column and how to change user's password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931991/mysql-what-does-stand-for-in-host-column-and-how-to-change-users-password)

Answer (score -1):

@ means at.
Like your email address.
For example, 'deletethisuser02'@'localhost' mean deletethisuser02 at localhost.
About what % mean, check the answer from this.
[MySQL: What does % stand for in host column and how to change user's password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931991/mysql-what-does-stand-for-in-host-column-and-how-to-change-users-password)

Comment: thanks @Sweetbarrow, maybe can you resume for me what is the `diference` into CREATE USER 'user'@'%' vs CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost'?

Comment: The difference is that USER@'%' can connect from anywhere, and USER@localhost can only connect from the same machine that's running the MySQL server.

Comment: @Sweetbarrow, please be sure you understand the question before answering, and please answer thoroughly.  If I asked what the difference was between a car and a bicycle, and received an answer that "a bicycle has two wheels," has my question been answered?

Comment: @VyR ```CREATE USER 'user'@'%'``` mean create user that can access from remote(no limitation), and ```CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost'``` can only be accessed from localhost. Error code 1396 when drop user mean user does not exist and same error code when create user mean user already exist. Check the document from here. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/drop-user/

Comment: Many thanks master @Dennis, now is so clear for me ``the difference``. Thanks @Sweetbarrow by your time, your help is very appreciated by me..